# "Cannot launch AVD in emulator" Android N preview emulator error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.0-nougat, android-n-preview

I have created android-n emulator but when trying to start it, i got this error.

[image]

I have android-n preview sdk and system image already installed.

**Note: Problem appears only in `Android-n` emulator, android `marshmallow` and `lolipop` emulators are working perfectly.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not an AVD problem. You basically have the best answer written in your image. Zoom out and try links. You're using 2 hypervisors 1 for AVD on top of Virtual Box, which doesn't like it because it tries to allocate registers VB has already allocated(it will crush if you take them out, because its not worked out yet). Solution: use another hypervisor or OS.

Comment: already gone through those links, but no help. Its working sometimes and sometimes giving this error. **Solution: use another hypervisor or OS.** so i don't think this would be a solution.

Comment: What do you mean you don't think. You **can't use Virtual Box**. period. That's what they basically tell you there. just use another system. This is VB issue has nothing to do with android.

Comment: or just use your phone;) Unless, of course, you will reprogram nuts and bolts of VirtualBox..

Comment: The fact that it works sometimes and sometimes not doesn't mean that its a simple error. When it works it simply means that the sets of allocated registers did not cross. It's mostly an undefined behaviour, not smth that you can control(I hope you know what "registers" are).

Comment: And solution that I proposed IS a solution because its obviously WORKS.
There nothing else to add to it.